# Service reference invalid error when trying to update my service

Tags: c#, wcf, service-reference

All of a sudden when I try to update or configure my `WCF` Service Reference I get the following error:

[image]

What might be the cause? Before that, it was working just fine.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using a service reference. Try getting rid of it all together and call your service using ChannelFactory. All your pain will go away.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though a similar issue had been asked/resolved from a previous stack overflow question reference: [Service Reference Error when trying to update or remove/add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173663/service-reference-error-when-trying-to-update-or-remove-add)

Comment: I've checked that answer and it doesn't help in my case. There must be something to do with Service References.